# How do I identify lists that start after a double newline or at the beginning of a document with Regex?

Tags: php, regex, multiline

Say I have the following block of text:

```
- one

some text
- should not start a list

- should start
- should continue

5. should also
6. more
```

I want to find three different lists here, the first line, the 6th and 7th lines, and the 9th and 10th lines.

So a list is valid if it begins with two newlines (it can't start only one line after a paragraph) or starts the document.

I tried: `^(?<=\n{2})(?:(?:(?:\-)|(?:\d\.))( {1,})[^\n]*\n?)*$` which uses a look-behind to check if there's two newlines before, and it works, but also causes it now to catch the `- one` list.

How do I say "two newlines before or starts the document" in Regex?

EDIT: To clarify it should be in multiline mode. And language is PHP.

Comment: You want the return to be...what?

Comment: *How do I say "two newlines before or starts the document" in Regex?* use `'(^|\n\n)'`

Comment: You did not specify your programming language, in `PCRE`(PHP, etc.) you could use [`(?:^|(?:\R{2}))[-\d]`](https://regex101.com/r/dH8cE1/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=\n{2}|^)(?:(?:-|\d+\.) +.*\n?)+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lS3gU9/2)

Positive lookbehind `(?<=\n{2}|^)` means if there are 2 preceding newlines or line start.

I've also refactored your regex a bit to remove redundant capturing groups.

Comment: Your regex is better, but, a little mod:

https://regex101.com/r/lS3gU9/2

You should match lists with items that begins with one or more digits.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, but this specifically doesn't work with multiline.

Comment: You don't need to use m or multiline flag with this regex. Check the demo link as well where I am just using global modifier

Comment: And you have to use `multiline` flag then use this regex [`(?<=\n{2}|\A)(?:(?:-|\d+\.) +.*\n?)+`](https://regex101.com/r/lS3gU9/3)

Answer (score 1):

You did not specifiy your programming language, in `PCRE` however (PHP, etc.), you could come up with the following regex:

```
(?:^|(?:\R{2}))[-\d]
# match the start (^)
# or two newlines
# followed by a dash or a digit
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dH8cE1/1).
If `\R` is not supported, try to subsitute it with `[\n\r]`, so that it becomes:

```
(?:^|(?:[\n\r]{2}))[-\d]
```

Comment: I completely failed to specify, but what if it's in multiline mode?

Comment: You could use the \A instead of ^

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex:

> `^(?:-|[0-9]).*|(?<=\n\n)(?:-|[0-9])(?:.|\n)*?(?=\n+[^-0-9]|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/bW1zH1/3

I assume that a 'list' begins with a hyphen or a number.